# Object methods in Blender3D?

Tags: python, oop, blender, bpy

I'm about 30 minutes into Blender's python API and I've been reading the documentation. Maybe I didn't look hard enough, but from what I'm seeing, I can't just assign an object (like an ico_sphere) to a variable named `Sphere` and then just modify its properties with methods?

```py
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="SELECT")
bpy.ops.object.delete()

Sphere = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(location=[0,0,0])

# Does something like this work?
Sphere.set_color('red')
```

I do a lot of `matplotlib` and I was wondering, if bpy has a similar interface that is object oriented like that?

Comment: Do `print(type(Sphere))` to see what you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In blender, an operator returns a status, which would usually be `{'FINISHED'}`.

After running an add object operator, the new object can be found in `bpy.context.object`.

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(location=[0,0,0])
Sphere = bpy.context.object
Sphere.location = (1,2,3)
Sphere.active_material = bpy.data.materials.new('mymat')
Sphere.active_material.diffuse_color = (1,0,0,1)
```

Note that node based materials need some more work. There is a blender specific SE site where you will find some script examples, like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23436/935).

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you also point me to the part of the docs where I can find all the properties I can change on an active object, or how I can find them out in blender? Is there a general way to find out through the console output? For example, I wanted to resize my sphere, but it didn't work with .radius or .size, as it said in one part of the documentation. The solution was .scale, which I only found out through another thread on stackoverflow...

Comment: @J.Doe You can find that in the [API docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html). You may also be interested in using blenders [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html), type something like `bpy.context.object.` and use auto-completion to see a list of available properties/methods.

Comment: I don't see any auto-completion. Is it mapped to another key in the editor than tab? Do I need to activate it?

Comment: @J.Doe the header button is not in 2.80, autocomplete is in the Console menu, or use the `Ctrl-Space` shortcut.